# How do you get a toddler to brush her teeth?

Tags: toddler, brushing-teeth

My 2-year-old daughter used to brush her teeth without problem. Now all of the sudden she fights not to. My wife gave up after a few days. I decided to take the simple approach and ask her if she wanted me to brush her teeth or for her to do it on her own.

She didn't want either so I let her know we're brushing teach and asked her to choose again. She was not interested so I forced the brush to touch a couple teeth. It was messy but we were doing bath time. The next morning she was glad to do it herself and showed off a little. I thought I was king but now, the next day, again she is fighting not to brush her teeth.

All her teeth are fine and there is nothing in her mouth to cause pain or anything like that. We had it checked out.

What do I do now to get her into brushing teeth?